# Family of functions with two horizontal asymptotes

Tags: functions, asymptotics

I'm looking for the equation of a family of functions that roughly resembles the sketch below (with apologies for the crudeness of said sketch):

[image: function sketch]

Properties I'm looking for:

- $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=y_1$ (i.e. approaches asymptote y=y<sub>1</sub>)
- $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=y_2$ (i.e. approaches asymptote y=y<sub>2</sub>)
- $|f'(x)|$ is at a maximum at *x*=0

I remember something involving e<sup>*x*</sup>/(??), but I can't remember exactly and can't seem to come up with the formula. I want to use it to weight tags in a tag cloud (i.e. the more recently a tag was used (smaller *x*), the more weight (larger *y*) the tag gets). The whole graph would be shifted up and to the right of what is shown in the sketch, but I know how to do that part once I have a formula.

Comment: In general, functions like this are called sigmoid, and wikipedia has a [list of several types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function). I provided one that is typically very easy to compute/understand.

Comment: Without looking at the wikipedia page ;) , the error function, the hyperbolic tangent, and the arctangent would have sigmoidal behavior. As a matter of fact, the integral of any "bell-shaped" curve will have sigmoidal behavior.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen awesome thanks.  there is ongoing discussion of this on metas- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263771/ban-imageshack-images-because-they-are-reusing-old-urls-for-advertising http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231613/disallow-new-embedded-images-from-hosts-other-than-the-se-imgur-account http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300232/ban-imageshack-images/302666

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a form of [logistic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function), such as $$f(x)=\frac{2}{1+e^x}-1.$$

[image: graph]

*edit*: For your specific criteria with $y_1$ and $y_2$: $$f(x)=\frac{y_1-y_2}{1+e^x}+y_2.$$

*edit 2*: For comparison of my answer to the other two answers:

[image: comparison graph]

dashed/black: $\frac{2}{1+e^x}-1$; blue: $-\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan x$; red: $-\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$

Answer (score 7):

Just take $- tan^{-1} x$. Vary it appropriately for additional constraints.

Comment: Indeed, when I looked at the graph, I thought "well that's the graph of $-\tan^{-1}(x)$".

Answer (score 6):

Another famous family of functions that behave as you describe is those of form $y=\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$. (This function is actually the sine of the arctan function [George suggested](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2360/family-of-functions-with-two-horizontal-asymptotes/2364#2364))

Graph of $y=-\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$:

[image: graph]

For a general y<sub>1</sub> and y<sub>2</sub>, the formula would be $y=-\dfrac{y_1-y_2}{2}*\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}+\dfrac{y_1+y_2}{2}$